# Order of execution if angular watchers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive that consists of around 15 watchers. Now i want to know in which order watcher wll execute. I have one scenario where i want watcher x to be run before watcher y.by default watcher y is running beforex

Answer (score 0):

add condition to check state of watcher x
if watcher was not executed yet -> return false